# how to display a loading image in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hello great Stackoverflow, am learning angular js and so am querying database records via angular js and everything works fine. now i want to display a loading image as the database content is loading and the image will fade off as soon as the content is loaded. please how do i achieve that. Thanks

below is the working code

```
var app = angular.module('angularTable', ['angularUtils.directives.dirPagination']);

app.controller('listdata',function($scope, $http){
    $scope.users = []; //declare an empty array

    $http.get("data.php").success(function(response){ 

        $scope.users = response;  //ajax request to fetch data into $scope.data
    });

    $scope.sort = function(keyname){
        $scope.sortKey = keyname;   //set the sortKey to the param passed
        $scope.reverse = !$scope.reverse; //if true make it false and vice versa
    }
});
```

Comment: I made an example for general $http requests using directive take a look if you like [here](https://jsfiddle.net/2yguh217/29/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add smth like `$scope.loading = true;` before `$http.get("data.php").success(function(response){` line.
And `$scope.loading = false;` inside success function.
In markup, smth like `<table ng-hide="loading">` and `<img ng-show="loading" src="loader.gif">`